# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown (SQL: select * from `actividades` where `actividades`.`id` = 3 limit 1)

Tags: php, laravel-5, crud

trato de realizar el update y delete desde el index pero cuando elijo el dato con su id me aparece esto

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'actividades.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `actividades` where `actividades`.`id` = 3 limit 1)

envia la id que quiero pero no entiendo ese limit 1 y no puedo llegar a la vista editar o eliminar el resgistro quedo atorado ahi.

```
public function edit($id_actividad)
{
    $Actividades = Actividades::find($id_actividad);
    $Tipos_Actividades = Tipos_Actividades::get();
    $Dependencias = Dependencias::get();
    return view('Actividades.edit',compact('Dependencias'), compact('Tipos_Actividades'), compact('Actividades'));    
}
```

Comment: ¿Con cuál de las 2 consultas genera el fallo?

Comment: me ayudaron a resolverlo pero me atore en otro error.

Comment: Considera publicar tu solución o eliminar la pregunta o editarla con el nuevo error

Comment: En el request no viene algún valor para: `id_tipo_actividad` y no puede quedar nulo por eso el error, debes darle valor

Comment: Los campos del request debieran llamarse igual que los campos en la tabla, o tú armar un array con los nombres correctos en el create